# Android Account Manager and starting another activity on successful login

Tags: java, android, accountmanager

I'm currently developing my app and I created simple authentication process. When user give login and password it sends data to server and it checks MySql database. I want to store user credentials in safe place which we know is Account Manager. I cant figure out how it works and how to apply it into my code.
Many tutorials that I found are old like 2010 or older..

This code works fine but I need to add changes. Like if user is succesfully logged in I want to start activity which will redirect him to MainPanel.class activity. I've tried to put code like this to SingnInActivity but it says method startActivity is not recognizable. Any ideas how to make it work?

```
 public void login(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, loginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Can anybody help me? I appreciate any help.﻿

My loginActivity looks like this:

```
public class loginActivity extends Activity {
private EditText usernameField,passwordField;
private TextView status,role;
public String d;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
    passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
    role = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
}



public void loginPost(View view){
    String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
//there I use another activity to 'sign in' 
    new SignInActivity(this,status,role).execute(username,password);
}
```

}

This is SignInActivity

```
public class SignInActivity extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

private TextView statusField,roleField;
private Context context;
String d;
public SignInActivity(Context context, TextView statusField, TextView roleField) {
    this.context = context;
    this.statusField = statusField;
    this.roleField = roleField;
}
protected void onPreExecute(){

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try{
            String username = (String)arg0[0];
            String password = (String)arg0[1];
            String link="http://myserver/index.php";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
                    (conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }

            d=sb.toString();
            return d;

        }catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result){

    if(result.equals("adminstrator")){
        this.statusField.setText("Yes");
//if user is in my database it changes statusfield to 'yes'
    }
    else{
        this.statusField.setText("No");
    }
    this.roleField.setText(result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `startActivity` in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It is in Activity class. If you don't understand what Inheritance is - start with that [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Change Context to Activity:

```
private Activity context;
public SignInActivity(Activity context, TextView statusField, TextView roleField) {
    this.context = context;
    this.statusField = statusField;
    this.roleField = roleField;
}
```

Then use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainPanel.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It solved one of my problems :)           Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, MainPanel.class);
context.startActivity(intent);  I used this.context instead of standalone this and it's working. Do you have any idea how to add AccountManager?

Comment: No - I don't realize what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `AccountManager` is, actually, pretty complicated.  You really just cannot drop it into an existing workflow.  You'll need an implementation of the `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`  that can be bound by the Android framework.  It will call your login activity as necessary.

There is a fairly understandable example in [this app](https://github.com/twitter-university/SyncAdapterYamba/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/twitter/university/android/yamba)

... and, incidentally, a good description of how it all works in my book, [Enterprise Android](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118183495)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will check your book. I think they have it in my college library.

Comment: Hope it works for you.  If it does, I'd appreciate the upvote/accept.